# Compare datetime > now with Jetbrains Exposed

Tags: mysql, sql, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I have the current table:

```
create table Tokens (
  token varchar(256) not null,
  duser varchar(32) not null,
  type varchar(16) not null,
  expires_in datetime not null,
  auth_time datetime not null,

  primary key(token),
  foreign key(duser) references User(id)
);
```

and i would like to make the query below:

```
select * from Tokens where duser = "myid" and expires_in > current_timestamp
--or something to compare if expires_in is greater than the current date **and** time
```

but I'm using [Exposed](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed). I already made this:

```
return transaction {
            Database.TOKENS.run {
                select {
                    (user eq this@DogoUser.id) and (expiresIn greater) //stopped here
                }
            }
        }
```

How to refear `current_timestamp` MySQL variable vith Jetbrains Exposed?

Answer (score 3):

There is CurrentDateTime expression in Exposed for that.

```
select {
   (user eq this@DogoUser.id) and (expiresIn.greater(CurrentDateTime()) 
}
```